# Axios ResponseRequest Blog Posts

Tags: node.js, axios

I am looking to use Axios in order to make a GET request to a Blog API transform the response and then make a POST request in order to send the transformed data back into the API. The reason for this is to remove additional Wordpress Markup from my blog. I am able to make a Request to a Single Blog post transform the response and then make a post request and this properly submits the data which is return in the "post_body". Now I am trying to do this for all of my blog posts but as the data structure has now changed all of the blog posts are within an objects array so I want to use forEach in order to loop through the array of objects and return the element. I keep getting an undefined response. Does anyone have any recommendations.

```
axios.get(allPosts, {
    transformResponse: axios.defaults.transformResponse.concat(function(data, headers) {
        // use data I passed into the function and the objects from the API
        // pass in data into the function using forEach this will return an array
        data.objects.forEach(function(data) {
            // use the returned array on Objects.key to find the name of the array
            Object.keys(data).forEach(function(k) {
                // if the key equals execute code
                if (k ==  "post_body") {
                    // fire Regex
                    data[k] = i[k].replace(regExp, '');
                }
            })
        })
        // return data
        return data.objects;
    })
})
.then(function(res) {
    console.log(res.data.post_body);
})
```

// Sample Data from API

```
{
"limit": 20,
"objects": [
    {
        "allow_comments": true,
        "post_body":"<p>Sample Blog Post</p>",
        "use_featured_image_in_summary": true,
        "uses_default_template": false,
        "weekly_notification_email_id": "5489696311"
    }
],
"offset": 0,
"total": 5,
"total_count": 5
```

}